# How can I generate an HTML report in python?

Tags: python, html, gitlab

I have written a python script that shows the differences in the repo branches of GitLab using GitLab API. Now my task is to write an HTML report to this script. I referred to many pages but I did not understand how and where exactly I can start?

My script output is like:

```
Listing Differences Between Branches: main and branch1 

No Reference found in :
second project
newpro

Nothing to compare in :
third project

Following are repos with changes :

fourth project
+------+-------------------+------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+----------+
| S.NO |   Commit Message  |      Author      |                                               URL                                               |    Date    |   Time   |
+------+-------------------+------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+----------+
|  1   | added second line | Ganesh Thirumani | https://gitlab.com/mygroup1316/fourth-project/-/commit/39e8806f364827544683934e3967c321f3b21678 | 2022-02-08 | 10:18:48 |
|  2   |  added third line | Ganesh Thirumani | https://gitlab.com/mygroup1316/fourth-project/-/commit/3f3a9ed7d1ab8fa4e6bb7ae6fa68c3b97b1f94b4 | 2022-02-08 | 11:13:20 |
|  3   |  added third line | Ganesh Thirumani | https://gitlab.com/mygroup1316/fourth-project/-/commit/f75946ce53b78669dbe813d8f3f2402f276ec862 | 2022-02-08 | 12:15:13 |
+------+-------------------+------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+----------+

first_project
+------+------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+----------+
| S.NO |  Commit Message  |      Author      |                                              URL                                               |    Date    |   Time   |
+------+------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+----------+
|  1   |  latest commit   | Ganesh Thirumani | https://gitlab.com/mygroup1316/first_project/-/commit/a39c795bfd0699343d956098023b21527192532f | 2022-02-07 | 04:47:40 |
|  2   | latest commit1.0 | Ganesh Thirumani | https://gitlab.com/mygroup1316/first_project/-/commit/b596f57b830d5c0c2f9b491f836a5974b65bcdba | 2022-02-07 | 06:06:20 |
+------+------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+----------+
```

How can I make an HTML report to this output and where do I start?
and also Do I need to learn all the HTML to write this?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

As you appear to be using Markdown as your current output format, you can use the [python-markdown](https://python-markdown.github.io/) package to convert it to HTML.

There are also tutorials on how to do that, for example [How To Use Python-Markdown to Convert Markdown Text to HTML](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-python-markdown-to-convert-markdown-text-to-html)

Comment: thank you so much, it helped me to get start the work...